# Eclipse JFace TreeViewer with expansion markers "+" and "-"

Tags: eclipse, treeview, swt, jface

I am trying to run an example on eclipse JFace to populate directory structure which involves treeview. By executing the code, I get something like this :

[image: Current Output]

Which is fine, directory structure is populated properly. However, as you can notice there is no way to differentiate if the current selection is a "File" or a "Directory" until I move my cursor, the TreeView then displays a ">" sort of sign to tell me if this is directory. Where as I want something more intuitive like a "+" sign to specify all the item (without focusing on the TreeView), which is like this :

[image: Required View]

Can someone please guide me how to achieve the same? I am using eclipse Kelper, Windows 7 x64.

Comment: [This answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16844497/1740724) might be an option. Note however, that this is OS specific, i.e. I tried it on Linux and it didn't work as expected, but on Windows at least it seems to work fine.

Comment: I tried it, but apparently SWT/System still draws its own expander ( a little triangle) over the supplied image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: you cannot change the appearance of the *expansion markers*.

The JFace `TreeViewer` uses the SWT `Tree` widget to display its data. SWT in turn accesses the native UI libraries of the operating system and hence the appearance of widgets is controlled by the respective native UI library.

Comment: so does that mean it is impossible? I mean no way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: It definitely contradicts the design of SWT to rely on the native look & feel. You may have a look at `PaintListener` to see if they provide a way to draw things other than the actual content of a `TreeItem`. Or resort to another UI toolkit that gives you more freedom over styling the widgets.

Comment: Can I change them to visible always (if the item has children). That can still solve my problem. Currently, the "markers" hides out as soon as focus is shifted to another widget/window. I would like it to stay there. Any clue?

Comment: I am not sure if this behavior is configurable in Windows at attl. At least, there is no SWT API to change this behavior.

Comment: Is there a method to tell SWT / java compiler to load a specific version of microsoft windows common control?

Comment: From where the SWT shared library (contains the JNI code) is to be loaded can be influenced (see class `Library`). But AFAIK to which version of comctl.dll this library binds cannot be influenced.